# La programacion de los eventos de los botones que tenia en el "shown.bs.modal" la tuve que mover al "done" del ajax que muestra el dialogo

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap-4, adminlte

Necesito me expliquen la siguiente situación, tal vez se trate de problema de propagación de eventos.

Actualizando de AdminLTE2 a la version 3 (ahora con Bootstrap 4.6) me he encontrado con una serie de situaciones que he ido solventando y en este caso aunque lo he resuelto me queda la duda. Notar que todo funciona como se espera en la version de AdminLTE2, los cambios deberian ser minimos y mas dirigidos a las clases de Bootstrap.
En la programacion del evento click de una etiqueta ancla a manera de boton desde la vista principal de la aplicacion, se muestra una vista que es cargada via ajax e insertada en el body de un modal. Esa vista contiene un select convertido en select2, y dos botones (etiquetas anclas a manera de boton) asi como dos paneles, uno con consultorios medicos sin vincular al Consejo popular seleccionado, y otro con los consultorios medicos ya vinculados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anteriormente la programacion de los botones para vincular y desvincular (los dos chevrones), asi como el evento `change` del select, yo la hacia en el evento `shown.bs.modal` y he tenido que moverla para el `donde` de la funcion `ajax` que carga el contenido del modal, por supuesto referenciando los mismos desde el document.body que es donde se inserta el div que se convierte en dialogo durante la llamada al dialogo. Ademas que tenia separado la conversion del select a select2 (esto lo hacia en la misma vista que se carga en el modal) de la programacion del evento change que antes se la hacia al elemento select como tal; ahora lo hago todo junto sobre el select2 como tal y al evento `change.select2`

Esta es la programacion actual, fijarse que el mayor cambio para que funcione ha sido: trasladar la programacion de los botones vincular y desvincular (chevrones), la creacion del select2 y su evento change desde el 'shown.bs.modal' hacia el `done` de la peticion ajax inicial que carga el contenido del dialogo.

```
$('#vistas').on('click', '#lnkCMFxCP', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var elementoTrigger = $(this);
        var url = elementoTrigger.data('src');

        var _dialogoConfig = {'modal-dialog-textsize': 'text-md', 'modal-dialog-width': '', 'modal-dialog-scrollable': '', 'modal-dialog-fullscreen': ''};
        var _tmpModalDialogTextSize = elementoTrigger.data('modal-dialog-textsize');
        var _tmpModalDialogWidth = elementoTrigger.data('modal-dialog-width');
        var _tmpModalDialogScrollable = elementoTrigger.data('modal-dialog-scrollable');
        var _tmpModalDialogFullScreen = elementoTrigger.data('modal-dialog-fullscreen');

        if (_tmpModalDialogTextSize !== undefined) {
            _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-textsize'] = _tmpModalDialogTextSize;
        }

        if (_tmpModalDialogWidth !== undefined) {
            _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-width'] = _tmpModalDialogWidth;
        }

        if (_tmpModalDialogScrollable !== undefined) {
            _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-scrollable'] = _tmpModalDialogScrollable;
        }

        if (_tmpModalDialogFullScreen !== undefined) {
            _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-fullscreen'] = _tmpModalDialogFullScreen;
        }

        Pace.track(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url
            }).done(function (data) {
                $(document.body).find('#modalVincularCMF').remove();
                $(document.body).append("<div class='modal " + _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-textsize'] + "' id='modalVincularCMF' tabindex='-1'><div class='modal-dialog " + _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-width'] + " " + _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-scrollable'] + " " + _dialogoConfig['modal-dialog-fullscreen'] + "'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header bg-lightblue'><h6 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>CMFs por Consejo Popular</h6><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div><div class='modal-body'><div id='contenidoModal' class='container-fluid'></div></div><div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button></div></div></div></div>");
                $(document.body).find('#modalVincularCMF').find("#contenidoModal").html(data);

                $(document.body).find('#consejosPopulares').select2({
                    theme: 'bootstrap4',
                    dropdownParent: $('#contenidoModal'),
                    width: '100%',
                    language: 'es',
                    multiple: false
                }).on('change.select2', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var seleccionado = $(this).val();
                    if (seleccionado !== "-1") {
                        Pace.track(function () {
                            $.ajax({url: Routing.generate('consejoPopular_CMFs', {'id': seleccionado})
                            }).done(function (data) {
                                $('#cmfVinculados').html(data);
                            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                    toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                                        timeOut: 2100,
                                        preventDuplicates: false,
                                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                        progressBar: true,
                                        showDuration: 800,
                                        hideDuration: 400,
                                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                        showEasing: "swing",
                                        hideEasing: "linear",
                                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                        hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                    });
                                } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                    toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                                        timeOut: 2500,
                                        preventDuplicates: false,
                                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                        onHidden: function () {
                                            window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, '', {
                                        timeOut: 3000,
                                        preventDuplicates: false,
                                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                        progressBar: true,
                                        showDuration: 800,
                                        hideDuration: 400,
                                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                        showEasing: "swing",
                                        hideEasing: "linear",
                                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                        hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } else {
                        $('#cmfVinculados').html('');
                    }
                });

                /**
                 * Evento btn Vincular
                 * **/
                $(document.body).find('#btnVincular').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var btn = $(this);
                    var consejoPopularId = $(document.body).find('#consejosPopulares option:selected').val();

                    if (consejoPopularId !== "-1") {
                        var arregloCMFs = [];
                        $(document.body).find("#cmfDesvinculados option:selected").each(function () {
                            arregloCMFs.push($(this).val());
                        });

                        if (arregloCMFs.length > 0) {
                            if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                                Pace.track(function () {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: Routing.generate('consejoPopular_vincularCMFs', {'consejoPopularId': consejoPopularId}),
                                        data: {'cmfs': arregloCMFs},
                                        beforeSend: function () {
                                            btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                            btn.find('span').removeClass('fas fa-chevron-right').addClass('fas fa-async-alt');
                                        }
                                    }).done(function (data) {
                                        if (data === "success") {
                                            $("#cmfDesvinculados option:selected").each(function () {
                                                $('#cmfVinculados').append($("<option></option>")
                                                        .attr("value", $(this).val())
                                                        .text($(this).text()));
                                                $('#cmfDesvinculados').find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                            toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                                                timeOut: 2100,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                progressBar: true,
                                                showDuration: 800,
                                                hideDuration: 400,
                                                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                                showEasing: "swing",
                                                hideEasing: "linear",
                                                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                            });
                                        } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                            toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                                                timeOut: 2500,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                onHidden: function () {
                                                    window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, '', {
                                                timeOut: 3000,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                progressBar: true,
                                                showDuration: 800,
                                                hideDuration: 400,
                                                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                                showEasing: "swing",
                                                hideEasing: "linear",
                                                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }).always(function () {
                                        btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                        btn.find('span').removeClass('fas fa-async-alt').addClass('fas fa-chevron-right');
                                    });
                                });
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                /**
                 * Evento btn Desvincular
                 * **/
                $(document.body).on('click', '#btnDesvincular', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    var btn = $(this);
                    var consejoPopularId = $('#consejosPopulares option:selected').val();

                    if (consejoPopularId !== "-1") {
                        var arregloCMFs = [];
                        $("#cmfVinculados option:selected").each(function () {
                            arregloCMFs.push($(this).val());
                        });

                        if (arregloCMFs.length > 0) {
                            if (!btn.hasClass('disabled')) {
                                Pace.track(function () {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: Routing.generate('consejoPopular_desvincularCMFs', {'consejoPopularId': consejoPopularId}),
                                        data: {'cmfs': arregloCMFs},
                                        beforeSend: function () {
                                            btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                            btn.find('span').removeClass('fas fa-chevron-left').addClass('fas fa-async-alt');
                                        }
                                    }).done(function (data) {
                                        if (data === "success") {
                                            $("#cmfVinculados option:selected").each(function () {
                                                $('#cmfDesvinculados').append($("<option></option>")
                                                        .attr("value", $(this).val())
                                                        .text($(this).text()));
                                                $('#cmfVinculados').find("option[value='" + $(this).val() + "']").remove();
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                            toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                                                timeOut: 2100,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                progressBar: true,
                                                showDuration: 800,
                                                hideDuration: 400,
                                                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                                showEasing: "swing",
                                                hideEasing: "linear",
                                                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                            });
                                        } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                                            toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                                                timeOut: 2500,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                onHidden: function () {
                                                    window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, '', {
                                                timeOut: 3000,
                                                preventDuplicates: false,
                                                positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                                                progressBar: true,
                                                showDuration: 800,
                                                hideDuration: 400,
                                                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                                                showEasing: "swing",
                                                hideEasing: "linear",
                                                showMethod: "fadeIn",
                                                hideMethod: "fadeOut"
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }).always(function () {
                                        btn.toggleClass('disabled');
                                        btn.find('span').removeClass('fas fa-async-alt').addClass('fas fa-chevron-left');
                                    });
                                });
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });


                $(document.body).find('#modalVincularCMF').modal({
                    keyboard: false,
                    backdrop: 'static'
                }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //var dialogo = $(this);
                }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(document.body).find('#modalVincularCMF').remove();
                });
            }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    toastr.error("Conexión interrumpida!!!", '', {
                        timeOut: 2100,
                        preventDuplicates: false,
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                        progressBar: true,
                        showDuration: 800,
                        hideDuration: 400,
                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                        showEasing: "swing",
                        hideEasing: "linear",
                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                    });
                } else if (jqXHR.status === 401) {
                    toastr.error("Su sesión ha expirado. No es posible realizar la operación.", '', {
                        timeOut: 2500,
                        preventDuplicates: false,
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                        onHidden: function () {
                            window.location = _HOMEPAGE;
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    toastr.error(jqXHR.responseText, '', {
                        timeOut: 3000,
                        preventDuplicates: false,
                        positionClass: 'toast-top-center',
                        progressBar: true,
                        showDuration: 800,
                        hideDuration: 400,
                        extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                        showEasing: "swing",
                        hideEasing: "linear",
                        showMethod: "fadeIn",
                        hideMethod: "fadeOut",
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    })
```

;

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta puntual?

Comment: Me llama la atención que al cambiar de admilte2 a admilte3, tuve que mover la programación de los eventos de los botones y el select2 hacia el done del Ajax que carga la vista del formulario dentro del modal cuando antes estaban declarados en el show.bs.modal porque dejó de funcionar, y me ha quedado la duda porque tengo otros modal con programaciones de eventos y de hacen en el show.bs.modal